# How to convert to editable table without losing web connection to query or losing manual date

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

So basically I am having a table with the columns S.No, Name, Lvl, ALvl, No of Creds, Creds Req, Max Creds, ACreds, Rating, Cred Collected. The only things which I get from website are Name, Lvl, Cred Collected (in this particular order). So I need only those to update while the rest I can calculate using Excel Formulas and some through manual updation. The only problem is every time the query updates, I lose all the other column values (goes back query default I kept when creating it). Any idea if that is possible.

Comment: Update: For some reason creating a new worksheet and adding the query to that table worked. Now my question is whether there is a way to stop rows from rearranging every time data refreshes. (Currently, I just created a S.No column and sort it ascending after a refresh.)

Answer (score 1):

When you have an outside information association, you can use the connection properties to point to another database table or query. You can even compose your own SQL explanations. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the language that relational database systems (such as Microsoft Access) use to perform various tasks. You can pass instructions right from Excel by using SQL statements. This can give you more power over the information you maneuver into your Excel model.
Albeit a nitty-gritty conversation of SQL is unimaginable, how about we stage somewhat outside our customary range of familiarity and alter our outer information association utilizing a straightforward SQL explanation to pull in an alternate arrangement of information.

Go to the Data tab on the Ribbon and select Connections. This activates the Workbook Connections dialog box shown here.
Choose the connection you want to edit and then click the Properties button.
The Connection Properties dialog box opens. Here, you can click the Definition tab.

Change the Command Type property to SQL and then enter your SQL statement. In this case, you can enter: 
SELECT * FROM [Sales_By_Employee]
WHERE ([Market] = ' Tulsa')This statement tells Excel to pull in all records from the Sales_By_Employee table where the Market equals Tulsa.

Click OK to confirm your changes and close the Connection Properties dialog box.

Excel immediately triggers a refresh of your external connection, bringing in your new data.

Comment: On the website there are 98 rows and I want all 98. I need to add columns in between a query where I can enter/edit data without it disappearing when website columns update.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this seems to be the default behavior.

When data is taken from the web site, it automatically populates all the data in the current table and is directly empty if the corresponding cell does not have data.

As a workaround, I suggest you create a second table, set the corresponding fields in this table, and then copy the corresponding data to the original table